# Linux Mint System wont boot :( Fsck clean - Any suggestions?

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I've just made some changes to my PC which now won't boot. I am attempting to install a new graphics card, and so have installed a RAM upgrade and I have also connected up a new hard drive, which is meant to be unrelated to my Linux build (it's used to run the Windows config my brother uses on the same computer).

My system is running a 1TB main disc, the Windows 250GB disc mentioned above, and a 250GB mounted drive which I set up a while back. Being new to this stuff, I think I managed to mount the extra disc incorrectly, since next time I booted I was dropped into recovery mode and got bailed out by some utility helpfully fixing the errors for me - sorry, can't remember the name or specifics of this, but figured it might be important.

Now, I made all the changes listed above, and for a while it was dropping me into recovery mode, now I just get a blinking cursor. Following some advice online, I booted into Mint from a Live USB and ran fsck on the two drives, both of which came back clean, so I'm a little stuck on what to do next. Any suggestions?

Final piece of info - I think the drives were set up incorrectly because my main 1TB drive is listed as /dev/sdb1, whereas the 250GB drive is at /dev/sda. I think this was probably the reason why when I booted a while back it had to correct these errors - it was trying to boot of /dev/sda by default? Just a thought ...

Any ideas would be much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: If you revert all the hardware changes does the system boot? If so, apply the changes one at a time until you hit the failure point.

Comment: I have reverted the hard drive setup to the previous point; I have a new power supply unit and RAM setup which I assume can't be to blame? The reverted system as mentioned still does not boot unfortunately

Comment: RAM could easily be to blame - either if it's mis-seated or if it's faulty